# Не могу разобраться с запятой, подскажите пожалуйста!

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая, если предложение построено именно так:

Спустится по лестнице, ступит на землю (?) страх и сомнения презирающий Иван.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запята *не* нужна. Из Розенталя ( http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109 ):

> *Не обособляются распространенные определения: 
>   
>  1) стоящие **перед** существительным [здесь: имя собственное] и не имеющие добавочных
>   обстоятельственных оттенков значения*

При ином порядке слов запятая может понадобиться:

> Спустится по лестнице, ступит на землю Иван, страх и сомнения
>   презирающий.